# java and android keystore path issue

Tags: java, android, keystore

I am exporting certificate, but the problem is how to get to the path of openssl in msdos. please help.

path of open ssl: C:\cygwin\bin

[image: how to set path of openssl using command tool]

Comment: The prompt does not look like Cygwin bash but like Windows Command Prompt (which has nothing to do with MS-DOS). Why don't you use Cygwin bash when it is installed? Then the path is correct.

Comment: ok i got it working its just "  " quotes missing from cygin to openssl....anyways thanks to all for helping it out :)

Answer (score 3):

**To generate a new one you must delete the existing debug.keystore file**.

Its location is *platform dependent* - you can find it in `Preferences - Android - Build - Default debug key store`.

You can create your own debug certificate in debug.keystore with whatever expiration you want(min 25year). Do this in the .android folder under your HOME directory:

> keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey
>   -storepass android -keypass android -keyalg RSA -validity 14000

For Detail Informations 
[check this link](http://www.abtevrythng.com/2010/06/adding-cer-certificates-on-your-android.html)
 and
[check this](http://www.bsp-gmbh.com/hercules/herc_cygwin.html)

Comment: Thanks,,,but the problem is kind of very simple its just the msdos command which i am not writing correctly. I need to replace the highlighted portion with correct " " marks.

Comment: Right click on my computer and select properties. Theres a section in there for environment variables on the advanced tab. The path variable is in there, just add a semicolon and then the cygwin path to the end of the existing value.